# Undefined Index in php add function

Tags: php, mysql

Here i'm going to do a insert to the MySQL.but here i'm getting error.I saw there's a duplicated for the same but in those answers they asked to add ISSET.In my coding i added that also but still i'm getting this error.

> Error 1 : Notice: Undefined index: Description in ....... add.php on line 8
>   Error 2 : Notice: Undefined variable: _FILE in ..........\add.php on line 9
>   Error 3 : Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in ....add.php on line 12

Here i added my Coding below

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
$Image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILE['Image']));
$Categories  = $_POST['category']; 
$ModifiedBy = 1;
$ModifiedDate = NOW(); 
$query1=mysql_query("insert into testdb      values('','$Title','$Description','$Image','$Categories','$ModifiedBy',$ModifiedDate,1)");
  if($query1)
  {
  header("location:list.php");
  }
  }
  ?>
  <fieldset style="width:300px;">
  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Title: <input type="text" name="Title"><br>
  Description: <input type="text" name="description"><br>
  Image : <input type="file" name="Image" /><br>
  <select name="category" id="category">
  <option>Choose</option>
  <option value="1">new</option>
  <option value="2">info</option>
  <option value="2">Event</option>

  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
  </fieldset>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: These are php errors. When the form is filled in there is no value in Description (partly because the field name is description with a lower case d) or Image (probably the same reason) - however you should check that values exist anyway. NOW() is a MySQL function. You probably want the PHP date() function.

Comment: You have a letter-case issue. `A != a` < example - as for `_FILE` - `S` perhaps? ;-) and don't use `NOW()` as a variable.

Comment: **By building SQL statements with outside variables, you are leaving yourself open to SQL injection attacks.**  Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like a name of "O'Malley", will blow up your SQL query. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. My site http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has many examples in detail.

Comment: Plus, I suggest you use **actuals** instead of `hopefuls` - Doing `insert into testdb` is like hitting a dozen golf balls at night, hoping they'll land in the right hole.

Answer (score 1):

You have grammar issues in your code. It should be this:

```
$Title=$_POST['Title'];
$Description=$_POST['description'];
$Image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']));
$Categories  = $_POST['category']; 
$ModifiedBy = 1;
$ModifiedDate = 'NOW()'; 
$query1=mysql_query("insert into testdb values('','$Title','$Description','$Image','$Categories','$ModifiedBy',$ModifiedDate,1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error 1: Case of "description" is wrong!

Error 2: it should be $_FILES (add an S). Also that is not how you handle file uploads -  
[read more here][1]

Error 3: NOW() is a mysql tag. not php. you can use date() if you want this in php.
```

Answer (score 0):

$_FILE should probably be [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), just a typo there. The linked page will give you a bit more information about how to post files using PHP.

The NOW() function is for mysql, not PHP. You can use php's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format to emulate the way MySQL saves dates instead:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

For the Description  error, that's to do with casing. Description != description. Try and be consistent with casing where you can, that often helps when looking for errors. Also, space your code out a little and make use of indentation.

When in doubt over an error, I usually check what line I get the error on. If it's one I've not encountered before, try a search and see if something similar comes up. @John Conde's link in his comment is a great place to start